# How to make the object I'm exporting as fbx to be in the middle of the scene when I import it?

Tags: export, import, .fbx

So I am exporting a lot of characters from one single file. The characters are on a line, so when I export them, they are not in the middle of the scene. How do I export the the character to fbx while the character is not in the middle, but when I import it, it is in the middle? How do I achieve that? It is a little bit hard to explain but here is a better explanation with screenshots.

When I export the character:

[image: When I export the character:]

When I import the character:

[image: When I import the character:]

What I want it to look like when importing the character (without having to move it to the middle when exporting, because I am going to export so many characters it would be too much of a hassle):

[image: What I want it to look like when importing the character (without having to move it to the middle when exporting, because I am going to export so many characters it would be too much of a hassle):]

Answer (score 1):

Its not uncommon to do an export script that center the model apples transformation tringulates etc and then export each model according to a naming convention to a specific directory for the current project.

If you are doing these type of tasks often it might be worth the effort.